# Getting data but POST, PUT, DELTE request not working on netlify

Tags: reactjs, heroku, netlify

My frontend is deployed on Netlify. all the get request working well but POST, PULL, DELETE request is not working.
My backend is on Heroku..

Is it CORS problem or else?
Thank you very much.

[this is my console after post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4j3n.png)

Comment: You will need to add more details about what is happening on the Heroku/backend side. Is it showing _any_ request being received but an invalid route, or is there no indication of an incoming request?

Comment: _Specifically, what does "not working" mean? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

From your linked screenshot, it appears that you're connecting to your API using relative URLs, for example: `/api/something`. Locally, this would most likely work as you'd most likely have your backend running too.

However, on production this would not work, because browsers will resolve `/api/something` relative to the domain which is now on Netlify. Since Netlify doesn't have your backend app running, and there is no asset at `/api/something`, Netlify sends back a 404.

The solution would be to use Netlify Rewrites: https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/. You could add something like:

```
/api/* https://your-heroku-url.com/:splat 200!
```

... in a file named `_redirects` which should be added to the publish folder on Netlify.

This would resolve `/api/something` to `https://your-heroku-url.com/something`. You might have to change the redirects based on your configuration.